# Query for row combine

Tags: sql-server

```
BEGIN
    declare @t1 table(
date1 date,
EmpID int,
bnumber varchar(24),
Name varchar(50),
Depname varchar(50),
mintime time,
maxtime time,
Status1 varchar(50))


insert into @t1 exec dbo.InOut2 @fromDate=@fdate,@toDate=@tdate


select distinct EmpID,
case when Status1='Present' then count (date1) end as 'Present',
case when Status1='Late-Absent' then count(date1) end as 'Late-Absent',
case when Status1='Absent'then count(date1)end as 'Absent' from  @t1
where date1 between @fdate and @tdate
group by EmpID, Status1
```

my output is like this

```
empid present late-absent  absent
124   null     null        3
124   null      5          null
```

but I want to see the output like these

```
empid  present  late-absent   absent
124     null          5           3
```

**EDITS:** - jcolebrand (brought in "answers" as edits with verbiage cleanup)

Instead of case what can I use to do this:

```
max(case when Status1='Present' then count (date1) end) as 'Present' ,
```

When I use this I get:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

The result is still same I do not get my expected result, it's still

```
empid   present   late-absent    absent
124      0          0              3
124      0          5              0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use COUNT inside another aggregate. What you're trying to do is add 1 for each row that meets the criteria, so use the CASE to return 1 or 0 depending of whether the criteria is met or not. Then aggregate the results of that CASE with a SUM:

```
SELECT EmpID,
SUM((CASE WHEN Status1='Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) end as 'Present',
SUM((CASE WHEN Status1='Late-Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) end as 'Late-Absent',
SUM((CASE WHEN Status1='Absent' THEN 1 end ELSE 0 END)) as 'Absent' from  @t1
where date1 between @fdate and @tdate
GROUP BY EmpID
```

I also removed Status1 from your aggregate, because it would create a separate row for each occurrence of *employee and Status1* - what you want is one row per *employee* only.

Comment: You could use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`: `COUNT(CASE WHEN Status1='Present' THEN 1 END)`

Comment: True, but when you use aggregate functions on a CASE that returns NULL values, you get those annoying "null value eliminated by an aggregate" warnings. ;)

Comment: @user42010, remember to mark the question as answered if this post solved your problem. :)